# Liveness Detection System - Suggestions

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to build a liveness detection system but till now I haven't been able to generate any significant results.
I read the article by pyimagesearch [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/03/11/liveness-detection-with-opencv/) on the same topic but no luck. Tried using some code from the already existing repos but no results.
I would like to know is there a particular approach if so, it'd be appreciated if you can explain it and if possible provide references, code, databases, etc. also.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you fail in using pyimagesearch? What actually did you tried and failed using pyimagesearch and other repos?

Comment: The common issue I had with repos other than pyimagesearch was the lack of datasets that they used in the implementation, as for the pyimagesearch one is that it uses the neural network to classify the faces but even after providing a variety of faces for it learn in each category I didn't got any significant results.